# Why does this usage of Object.assign make my clone method work incorrectly?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create an ES6 class that has its own clone method allowing itself to be cloned.  This should create a new instance of the class, and copy over all of its public data to the new instance.  I'm implementing the class like so:

```js
class TestCloneable {
    constructor(someVal) {
        if (someVal) { this.someVal = someVal; }
    }

    clone = () => {
        const cloned = new TestCloneable(this.someVal);
        Object.assign(cloned, this); // same behaviour for Object.assign(cloned, {...this});
        return cloned;
    };
}

let test1 = new TestCloneable(1);
test1.anotherVal = 2;
let test2 = test1.clone();
test2.anotherVal = 3;
let test3 = test2.clone();

console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
console.log(test3);
```

What I don't understand is why `test3.anotherVal` is 2.  I set it to 3 on `test2`, then cloned `test2`.  Somehow my usage of `Object.assign` seems to be causing `this` to refer back to `test1` within the `clone` method of `test2` instead of refering to `test2` itself.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because this syntax `clone = () => { }` doesn't create a method, it creates a property

Use correct syntax and it will work

```js
class TestCloneable {
    constructor(someVal) {
        if (someVal) { this.someVal = someVal; }
    }

    clone() {
        const cloned = new TestCloneable(this.someVal);
        Object.assign(cloned, this);
        return cloned;
    };
}

let test1 = new TestCloneable(1);
test1.anotherVal = 2;
let test2 = test1.clone();
test2.anotherVal = 3;
let test3 = test2.clone();

console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
console.log(test3);
```

When you used `Object.assign` you also copied the clone method including the `this` context. So next time you run clone this is still pointing to the first object.

Cloning everything except the `clone` function results in the expected behaviour:

```js
class TestCloneable {
    constructor(someVal) {
        if (someVal) { this.someVal = someVal; }
    }

    clone = () => {
        const cloned = new TestCloneable(this.someVal);
        cloned.anotherVal = this.anotherVal;
        cloned.someVal = this.someVal;
        return cloned;
    };
}

let test1 = new TestCloneable(1);
test1.anotherVal = 2;
let test2 = test1.clone();
test2.anotherVal = 3;
let test3 = test2.clone();

console.log(test1);
console.log(test2);
console.log(test3);
```

Comment: But shouldn't an arrow function's `this` resolve to the containing object instance?  I thought that was how it worked.

Comment: When you used `Object.assign` you also copied the `clone` method including the `this` context. So next time you run `clone` `this` is still pointing to the first object.

Comment: Right. Would an alternative be to filter out all functions from `{...this}` before passing it to Object.assign?

Comment: You could do that but I would just stick to a method syntax.